# Successful confirmation after message posted to Queue Asked today

Tags: azure, azure-servicebus-queues

When I am trying to post a message to a queue in Azure Service Bus message getting posted to the queue but not able to receive successful confirmation message.

While debugging I have noticed that, system control is exiting at this statement in my code

```
await client.SendAsync(brokeredMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

My Code:

```cs
string conString = "xxx";

Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.QueueClient client = new Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.QueueClient(conString, "queueName"); string messageBody = "xxx";

var brokeredMessage = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageBody)); brokeredMessage.ContentType = "application/JSON; charset=utf-8";

await client.SendAsync(brokeredMessage); // Exists from hear, not even throwing any exception as well.

await client.CloseAsync();
```

Any clue how to get read the response message.

Thanks

Comment: "not able to receive successful confirmation message" there's no confirmation message. The asynchronous operation either succeeds or fails. Also, it's better to provide a link to a simple repro. The code above looks fine as text 

Answer (score 0):

**Azure Queues** are meant for **async message passing**, not searching.

Moreover, this method has no return type and cannot give you any response. However, you can have a try catch to handle/know about any error.

**Azure Queues** can also let you [**peek the next message** without dequeuing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues?tabs=dotnet#peek-at-the-next-message).